# Log repeated values in 2d array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to optimise a whole school timetable. I have the timetable currently organised in a sheet. Teacher initials are the headings for each column and each row corresponds to a single teaching period in a 30 lesson week. Each cell contains the name of a class.

Currently I am looking for classes that are split between 2 teachers.

I am trying to make an appscript that will log the classname if it appears anywhere outside the current column (i.e. the same class is being taught by 2 or more different teachers at different times)

I'm aware that nesting loops is not the least efficient way of doing this but I just wanted to hack something together quickly to get the job done. Unfortunately this code is taking longer than the maximum permitted time. The array is only 30 rows by about 56 columns so I dont see why it's taking such a long time. (Cant see anything that's obviously infinite about my loops either)

Can anyone help? :)

```
function splitClassLocator() 
{
  //copy the sheet to a 2d array.
  //(1)descend through each column from vertical idx 3 to period6 idx36
    //(2)start at horiz idx 1, descend through each item vertically. 
      //if item from loop 1 matches item from loop 2 and loop 1 vertical index != loop 2 vertical index
         //log the item (split class)

  //GET THE DATA     
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var range = sh0.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  //COMPARE
  //main row mr, main col mc V compare row cr, compare col cc
  Logger.log("Rows = " + data.length + "cols = " + data[0].length);

  for (var mr = 2; mr < data.length; mr ++)
  {
    for (var mc = 1; mc < data[0].length; mc ++)
    {
      for (var cr = 2; cr < data.length; cr ++)
      {
        for (var cc = 1; cc, data[0].length; cc ++)
        {
          if (mc != cc) // if it's not comparing classes belonging to the same teacher
          {
            if ((data[mr][mc] != undefined) || (data[mr][mc] != null) || (data[mr][mc] != ""))
            {
              if (data[mr][mc] == data[cr][cc])
              {
                Logger.log(data[mr][mc]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than discard the information after your comparison, store it and use it! Welcome to the world of not-Arrays!

Your stated goal is to find classes that have more than two teachers. Thus, the minimum you need to do is tally this information on a single trip through the array.

```
function countTeachersPerClass() {
  const schedule = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("somename").getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = schedule.shift();
  const numTeachers = headers.length;
  // Store classes as properties in an Object.
  const classes = {};

  // Read the schedule array.
  // Assumption: time is in index 0, classes in all other.
  schedule.forEach(function (period) {
    var name = period[0];
    // Store each class in this period.
    for (var teacherIndex = 1; teacherIndex < numTeachers; ++teacherIndex) {
      // Have we seen this class? If no, initialize it.
      var classID = period[teacherIndex];
      if (!classes[classID])
        classes[classID] = {teachers: {} };
      // Add this teacher to its list of teachers.
      var tID = headers[teacherIndex];
      if (!classes[classID].teachers[tID])
        classes[classID].teachers[tID] = {periods: []};

      // Add this period for this teacher.
      classes[classID].teachers[tID].periods.push(name);
    } //End for loop over columns in a row.
  }); // End forEach over schedule's rows.

  // Log the object (in Stackdriver, for easy review and interactivity).
  console.log({message: "Built classes  object", input: schedule, result: classes, teachers: headers});

  // Make a report from it.
  const report = [["Class ID", /* other headers */]];
  for (var cID in classes) {
    // This particular report is for class with more than two teachers.
    if (Object.keys(classes[cID].teachers).length > 2) {
      var row = [cID];
      /** Push info to the row, perhaps with just the names
         of the teachers, or also including number of
         periods per each teacher, etc. */;
      // Add the completed report row to the report.
      report.push(row);
    }
  }

  // Log the report.
  console.info({message: "Report", report: report});
}
```

You could certainly get fancier by adding more properties to each classes object than just `teachers`, such as tracking the average consecutive taught time (i.e. which classes alternate teachers often), but I leave that as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Booom! That's fantastic. I wish I could teach my brain to problem solve like that! Too much real job getting in the way of my programming.

Comment: First, thanks so much! OK, working through this. There was a minor error (I think) just after  classes[classID].teachers[tID].periods.push(name);
    }
  } was missing a );

Comment: First, thanks so much! OK, working through this. There was a minor error (I think) just after  `code`classes[classID].teachers[tID].periods.push(name);
    }
  } `code`was missing a );  (Is that right, or did I break it?) Here is a dummy sheet, (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-ccgaE3_NQ0pznXuLf049gCwkud6c7h5loSzNsi27E/edit?usp=sharing) when I test it I get "0: [
    0:  "Class ID"     
   ]
   1: [
    0:  ""     
   ]" -- which doesn't seem right but I don't know enough about what you did to debug.

Comment: @SRICHARDS oops, I was missing the closing parenthesis of the`forEach`. Wrote it on mobile and haven't run it through the actual edited for syntax checking yet.

Comment: I've been going through your code quite a lot in the last couple of days. I've learned a lot from it, thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I cant understand why not. I've linked a "test" spreadsheet above, when I run your code on this test, in the report I only get one class in the report : "7YA/Sc". There should be several, for example 8YA/Sc, 8L/Gg etc. These should be pushed into the report and I cant understand why this is not happening.

Comment: I added a simple log instruction `Logger.log(Object.keys(classes[cID].teachers).length + " in " + cID);` just before the `if (Object.keys(classes[cID].teachers).length > 2)` which indeed shows a number of classes with multiple teachers, however only "7YA/Sc" is getting pushed to the report. I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: @SRICHARDS The original report-building stub i used here did not use any braces after the `for` loop initialization, since only a single statement (the `if`) was being checked for each class id. Adding a log statement ahead of that without adding braces means only the `Logger` statement is executed for each value of `cID`, and then the report row insertion will use the last value of `cID`. If you highlight your code and then press the Tab key, the Apps Script editor should auto-align your code to the proper indentation level, making loop body errors like this easy to find.

Comment: You have been more helpful than you probably realise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works a bit better, flattening to make 2 single dimensional arrays, one is the teacher to check and the other array is all the other timetables combined.

Still takes ages though:

```
function splitClasses()
{
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var range = sh0.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  var rows = data.length;
  var cols = data[0].length;  

  for (var col = 1; col < cols; col ++)
  { 
    var teacherTT = [];
    var othersTT = [];    
    for (var row = 2; row < rows; row ++)
    {
      teacherTT.push(data[row][col]);
    }


    for (var oCol = 1; oCol < cols; oCol ++)
    {
      for (var oRow = 2; oRow < rows; oRow ++)
      {
        if (col !=oCol)//dont add current teacher TT to others TT
        {
          othersTT.push(data[oRow][oCol]);
        }
      }
    }

    //Logger.log(othersTT);
    var tLength = teacherTT.length;
    var oLength = othersTT.length;

    Logger.log("tL" + tLength);
    Logger.log("oL" + oLength);

    for (var t = 0; t < tLength; t ++)
    {
      //Logger.log("t "+t);
      for (var o = 0; o < oLength; o ++)
      {
        if (teacherTT[t] != undefined ||teacherTT[t] != null || teacherTT[t] != "" || teacherTT[t] != " ")
        {
          if (teacherTT[t])
          {
            if (teacherTT[t] == othersTT[o])
            {
              //Logger.log("o "+o);
              Logger.log(teacherTT[t]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


  }

}
```